# Why are these dots not equal in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, text, nlp

I am working on texts and have the left dot from an input text and right dot typed from a keyboard. However, in Python, they are not being treated as equal.

```py
'․' == '.'
Out[870]: False
```

What could be a possible reason, and how can I recreate the left dot using the keyboard?

Comment: first character does not appear to be a true dot. It looks to be masquerading as a `.`, when actually it is a `․`.

Comment: You can directly search for the character on Google. Here are some links; https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+2024 https://unicode-table.com/en/2024/ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leader_(typography)

Comment: I'm not sure why there's a vote to close as "not reproducible or caused by a typo". The example given is clearly reproducible, and I find it hard to argue that this is a simple typographical mistake (i.e. no person would accidentally insert a Unicode character rather than a period).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The dot on the left is *not* a period: it is a [one dot leader](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+2024) Unicode character.

In Python, you can print it by using `"\u2024"`:

```py
print('\u2024')
```

This outputs:

```py
․
```

You can use this for comparison purposes as well. If you do:

```py
print('․' == '\u2024')
```

it will output

```py
True
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest going with `str.maketrans` in this case:

```py
trans_table = str.maketrans({'․': '.'})
print(trans_table)

# prints `False`
print('․' == '.')

# now prints `True`
print('․'.translate(trans_table) == '.')
# or:
#   '․'.replace('․', '.') == '.'
```

Comment: Why not with `replace()`?

Answer (score 0):

Basically, the visual representation of characters as we perceive them has no meaning from a machine's perspective.

Python compares the unicode values of those two values, and those obviously differ.

The dot on the left is "\u2024", whereas the dot on the right is "\u2e".